# How to get a visible frame around a tableview in a container view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, containers, uicontainerview

the subject says it all: I have a few UITableViews from an iPhone version of my app, that I want to use in the iPad version. For that I'm using the container view object, that "imports" the existing tableview inside of another (bigger) view-controller. Works fine.

But it looks kind of odd, since the borders of the tableview is not displayed. I the image below, you see the layout of the designer on the left side, my containerview on the right side. The "border-frame" on the right side is missing.

I wonder if there is a way to get this border. I the docs I didn't find anything helpful.

Q1: is there a standard property etc to get this frame?

Q2: if not - how would you guys do it? I guess, I could just put an empty view with the frames background color behind the container frame. Any better workaround out there?

[image]

Comment: You could use the border property of the view's CALayer. However, I don't know if that will be better than your workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about this issue but I think that it can be solved by using these properties

```
tableView.layer.borderColor = THE_COLOR;
tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
```

Also, you may want to use **[SparkInspector](http://sparkinspector.com)** or **[Reveal](http://revealapp.com)** to properly debug the UI. You can set and inspect any property that you want at runtime using these apps.

Comment: Thanks Artur, that was what I was looking for. I ideed use Reveal, but I kind of overlooked the CALayer in this case...

Comment: Setting the border property of a CALayer makes the border appear inside of the view/layer. With a table view that shows cells this should not work, as the cells overlap the border.

Answer (score 1):

Put the table view centered into a view that is 2 pt larger and set the `backgroundColor` of the outer view to the border color.